# Generic method from client to db in 3-tier-architecture

Tags: java, generics, architecture, methods

Should a business application rely on a generic method called "saveOrUpdate" from the remote client to the hibernate persistence layer?

Background: Our architect argues, that if the amount of use cases in the application are too many or not really determinable, it is ok to go generic over all. As you suggest I am not with him. How are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing that, you're migrating your business logic into the client, plain and simple.  That's not necessarily a bad thing; look at the HATEOAS requirement of REST, for example, for a situation where that's appropriate.  However, if you're trying to do this, you're breaking the paradigm that the server must be stateless; if the client specifies the "`saveOrUpdate`", then you're making the assumption that the server is maintaining state beyond the current session, which is architecturally a problem if you're ever going to want to scale your servers horizontally.  Essentially, if you're driving state from the client properly (as in a HATEOAS situation), your saves will occur as the requests are made, and you won't need a "`saveOrUpdate`"; if you really need that from your client, it's an indication that you've improperly migrated your business logic to the client.

Comment: We do have a stateless server and this is made a law as our architect says, that he wouldn't be in the project anymore if we change to a stateful server.

Answer (score 0):

If you go that route, are you really a 3-tier architecture, or just a 2-tier architecture with a monomolecular transparent "business" layer in the middle?

Comment: Rich-Client with swing, Spring remoting with httpinvoker, spring container, Tomcat, hibernate, oracle. The business layer is defined to be spread from client to db.